# Vector2 is off - libgdx/java

Tags: android, libgdx

```
game.batch.begin();
for (Array obstacle_array123: obstacle_array) {
    body = obstacle_array123;
    for (Body bodies: body) {
        if (bodies.getUserData() instanceof Array && bodies.isActive()) {
            sprites_array = (Array)bodies.getUserData();
            for (int fix_pos = 0; fix_pos < sprites_array.size; fix_pos++) {
                sprite = sprites_array.get(fix_pos);
                if (verts.size != 0) verts.removeRange(0, verts.size - 1);
                f = bodies.getFixtureList().get(fix_pos);
                s = (PolygonShape)f.getShape();
                transform = bodies.getTransform();

                for (int i = 0; i < s.getVertexCount(); i++)
                {
                    s.getVertex(i, tmp);
                    transform.mul(tmp);
                    verts.add(new Vector2(tmp));
                }
                rotation_point.set((verts.get(0).x + verts.get(1).x + verts.get(2).x + verts.get(3).x) / 4, (verts.get(0).y + verts.get(1).y + verts.get(2).y + verts.get(3).y) / 4);

                sprite.setPosition(rotation_point.x - sprite.getWidth() / 2, rotation_point.y - sprite.getHeight() / 2);
                sprite.setRotation(bodies.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
                sprite.draw(game.batch);
            }
        }
    }
}
game.batch.end();
```

I have a game where my bodies are made from multiple square fixtures, so this is the code to render each square sprite on each square fixture.

2 problems - 1.st --> it only renders the first sprite in the array
2.nd --> if you look at the following loop (SOLVED)

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.getVertexCount(); i++)
{
    s.getVertex(i, tmp);
    transform.mul(tmp);
    verts.add(new Vector2(tmp));
}
```

well it is apperantly different compared to

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.getVertexCount(); i++)
{
    s.getVertex(i, tmp);
    transform.mul(tmp);
    verts.add(tmp);
}
```

The spawned coordinates in 2nd example are wrong for half width and half height of the square.

When I try to get the coordinated from both examples the numbers are the same, but when setting the sprite position, 2nd example goes off.

Comment: What is the size of sprites_array?

Comment: Ok after trying every possible variable it came to this: found the error, more like a typo: for (int z = 0; i < 1; i++), that is why it kept throwing 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably ask both questions separately, but to answer your second question, then they ARE different.

In the first one you add a new `Vector2` to `verts` each time through the loop. So `verts` will end up holding a load of different `Vector2`'s.

In the second one you add the same `Vector2` to `verts` over and over again, so it will just have one `Vector2` with the same value over and over again (remember Java is pass by reference).

**Caveat** - My answer assumes that `verts` is some sort of standard collection or a libgdx `Array`.

Comment: oh yeah, my mistake (got caught in the proccess and totally missed it), seems like I have to create an array of tmp values, since I'm creating a game and don't want to use NEW in render loop